# typescript return with double bang sign

Tags: typescript

I'm following a tutorial online that uses double bang (!!) on an obj(line 2). I can't find any reference to explain what it is. Please help me to understand it. This is the code:

```
function hasName(obj: any): obj is {name: string} {
    return !!obj &&
        typeof obj === "object" &&
        "name" in obj
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: possible duplication of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/784929/what-is-the-not-not-operator-in-javascript

Comment: `!` - boolean NOT. When used with a non-boolean it will treat the argument as truthy/falsy and give you the opposite boolean value, e.g., `!0 = true` and `!1 = false`. using NOT again on the result will transform to the opposite boolean value - `!!0 = false`, `!!1 = true`